# How to override abstract class for await and async?

Tags: flutter, async-await, observable, abstract

How to override `await` or `async` ?

**Repository**

```
abstract class Repository {
    Observable<dynamic> addUpdateWorkImage(WorkImage workImage);
}
```

**RepositoryImpl**

```
@override
  Future<Observable> addUpdateWorkImage(WorkImage workImage) async {
    if (workImage.id.isEmpty) {
      final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
          FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('image.jpg'.toString());
      final StorageUploadTask task =
          firebaseStorageRef.putFile(workImage.imagePath);
          StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot = await task.onComplete;
      workImage.url = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      return Observable.fromFuture(
          endpoints.workImageCollectionEndpoint.add(workImage.toJson()));
    }
  }
```

**Error**

```
'RepositoryImpl.addUpdateWorkImage' ('(WorkImage) → Future<Observable<dynamic>>') isn't a valid override of 'Repository.addUpdateWorkImage' ('(WorkImage) → Observable<dynamic>').
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your abstract interface to return a `Future`.

```dart
abstract class Repository {
    Future<Observable<dynamic>> addUpdateWorkImage(WorkImage workImage);
}
```